# How to select suitable RAM for my machine?

Tags: memory

I have a Core i3 machine. Therefore, I know that I need is DDR3 RAM. Are there any other factors that I need to consider when I buy a RAM module?

I have already installed 2 GB. Here is more info:

```
Memory slots
  Total memory slots  2
  Used memory slots 1
  Free memory slots 1
Memory
  Type  DDR3
  Size  2048 MBytes
  Channels #  Single
  DRAM Frequency  665.2 MHz
  CAS# Latency (CL) 9 clocks
  RAS# to CAS# Delay (tRCD) 9 clocks
  RAS# Precharge (tRP)  9 clocks
  Cycle Time (tRAS) 24 clocks
  Command Rate (CR) 1T
Physical Memory
  Memory Usage  50 %
  Total Physical  1.91 GB
  Available Physical  972 MB
  Total Virtual 3.85 GB
  Available Virtual 2.45 GB
SPD
  Number Of SPD Modules 1
    Slot #1
      Type  DDR3
      Size  2048 MBytes
      Manufacturer  Unknown
      Max Bandwidth PC3-10700 (667 MHz)
      Part Number RMB2GB484CA4-13HC
      Week/year 19 / 11
      SPD Ext.  EPP
        JEDEC #4
          Frequency 685.7 MHz
          CAS# Latency  9.0
          RAS# To CAS#  9
          RAS# Precharge  9
          tRAS  25
          tRC 34
          Voltage 1.500 V
        JEDEC #3
          Frequency 609.5 MHz
          CAS# Latency  8.0
          RAS# To CAS#  8
          RAS# Precharge  8
          tRAS  22
          tRC 30
          Voltage 1.500 V
        JEDEC #2
          Frequency 533.3 MHz
          CAS# Latency  7.0
          RAS# To CAS#  7
          RAS# Precharge  7
          tRAS  20
          tRC 27
          Voltage 1.500 V
        JEDEC #1
          Frequency 457.1 MHz
          CAS# Latency  6.0
          RAS# To CAS#  6
          RAS# Precharge  6
          tRAS  17
          tRC 23
          Voltage 1.500 V
```

Here is the motherboard info

```
Manufacturer  Intel Corporation
Model DH61WW (LGA1155 CPU 1)
Chipset Vendor  Intel
Chipset Model Sandy Bridge
Chipset Revision  09
Southbridge Vendor  Intel
Southbridge Model H61
Southbridge Revision  B3
System Temperature  40 °C
  BIOS
    Brand Intel Corp.
    Version BEH6110H.86A.0020.2011.0218.1538
    Date  2/18/2011
  Voltage
    CPU CORE  0.960 V
    MEMORY CONTROLLER 1.104 V
    AVCC  3.440 V
    3VCC  3.440 V
    VIN4  1.048 V
    VIN5  1.056 V
    VIN6  1.056 V
  PCI Data
      Slot PCI
        Slot Type PCI
        Slot Usage  Available
        Bus Width Unknown
        Slot Designation  PCIe x16 Slot
        Slot Number 0
      Slot PCI
        Slot Type PCI
        Slot Usage  Available
        Bus Width 32 bit
        Slot Designation  PCI Slot
        Slot Number 1
      Slot PCI
        Slot Type PCI
        Slot Usage  Available
        Bus Width Unknown
        Slot Designation  PCIe x1 Slot
        Slot Number 2
```

If I add RAM modules for the rest of the empty sockets, what is the suitable type? This is for my personal work. I use this for development and gaming.

Comment: You'll need to specify your system specification, especially the motherboard. And while you're at it, what you're intending to do with your machine, i.e. gaming or office work.

Comment: Download the manual for the motherboard.  Intel also publishes a memory compatability for their platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/search/searchresults.aspx?keywords=DH61WW) you have two slots, each that can take a 8GB max stick of PC3-12800 (DDR3-1600) RAM for a max total of 16GB of RAM. However, [Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/desktop-board-dh61ww.html?wapkw=dh61ww) lists support for up to 16GB of DDR3 1333 MHz which is PC3-10600.

Currently you have a single stick of 2GB PC3-PC3-10666 (DDR3-1333) and conventional wisdom is to match the speed (though go for a higher capacity if you can).

You mention you have a Sandy Bridge i3 CPU and you are looking for better performance. If you listed more specs and what you goal is that would help, though I suspect if you [upgraded the CPU](http://processormatch.intel.com/CompDB/SearchResult.aspx?BoardName=DH61WW) to an i5 or i7 (and Ivy Bridge CPUs are supported by the H61 chipset; you wouldn't gain native USB3.0 support and other features though) you'd see a substantial performance gain.

Comment: If you do decide to upgrade your processor, I'd strongly recommend a bios update to the latest version available before you do a CPU swap, since you may need a update to support the new chip

Comment: it says `Max Bandwidth PC3-10700 (667 MHz)` not `2GB PC3-PC3-10666 (DDR3-1333)` right?

Comment: "Fractional frequencies are normally rounded down, but rounding up to 667 is common due to the exact number being 666⅔ and rounding to the nearest whole number. Some manufacturers also round to a certain precision or round up instead. For example, PC3-10666 memory could be listed as PC3-10600 or PC3-10700" [source Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#Modules)

Answer (score 1):

According to Intel's specifications for your particular [motherboard](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/desktop-board-dh61ww.html), it supports dual-channel memory on two memory banks. The current memory module fitted is 2GB rated at 10700 MHz (667 MHz operational), with 9-9-9-24 (CL9) timings.

What you can do is buy another memory module that has the same specifications as the one that you've got (2GB, 9-9-9-24/CL9, PC3-10700 or something similar) so you'll end up having 4GB of RAM. Since you're going to be using your system for development and gaming work, your best bet would be discarding your current 2GB module and instead going for an 8GB memory kit (that is, 2 x 4GB of RAM). Specs for the kit should be roughly the same, apart from the capacity (try to avoid the more expensive options). That way you'll have a bit of leeway with running multiple programs simultaneously and also improving overall system performance.